Proving a formula for the solution of this equation
I have a set $I_{N} = \{1,...,N\}$ for some $N \ge 1$ and two set functions $f: 2^{I_{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: 2^{I_{N}}\to \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f(\emptyset) = 1$, $g(\emptyset) = 0$ and that they are both related by:
$$f(X) = \sum_{\substack{Y \subset X \\ \min X \in Y}} g(Y)f(X\setminus Y).$$
I am trying to prove that $f$ is given by:
$$f(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{|X|} \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\substack{I_{1},...,I_{k} \neq \emptyset \\ I_{1}\cup \cdots \cup I_{k} = X \\ I_{i} \cap I_{j} = \emptyset}}\prod_{s=1}^{k}g(I_{s}).$$
My attempt was to show that this second expression satisfies the first formula, so it must be $f$. However, I could not finish the proof because the restriction $\min X \in Y$ in the first formula makes the combinatorics a bit difficult. Can someone help me, please?

Note that the second expression is a sum over (unordered) set partitions, concealed as a normalized sum over ordered set partitions with the $1/k!$ factor undoing the redundancies. Now note that each set partition of $X$ contains a unique block that contains $\min X$.
